# Cloud_RoleName inconsistently getting values via ILogger

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have an application (dotnet core 2.0) which is sending telemetry data to our AppInsights instance via the ILogger mechanism

`// Startup.cs :: Configure()
factory.AddApplicationInsights(app.ApplicationServices, LogLevel.Information);`

While this is working, and calls to `LogInformation()` and its siblings does indeed write to our AI, I'm noticing an oddity in that SOME of the records seem to be missing values for cloud_RoleName (and cloud_RoleInstance).

I am aware that I could provide a Telemetry initializer to manually set this value, and failing another solution, I'll fall back to this.  But, I'd like to understand whats going on here.  There doesn't seem to be any difference between calls that get the data applied, and those that don't.

The only difference I've seen yet (only just noticed, so haven't tested) is that one of the ones that works is in a class with the ILogger like so:

```
  private ILogger Logger { get; }
```

and one that doesn't work is like:

```
  private readonly ILogger<ConnexeoPartnerLoginHandler> _logger;
```

There are a few differences between those two, so I'll need to test some of those variations and see if they make any difference in the output.

### update

Changing to the ILogger property similar to the first one (the one that was working for another call) didn't make any difference for me. Didn't expect it to, but had to try.

Answer (score -1):

For the code which does not work, please try to initialize the field in a constructor method, like below:

```
private readonly ILogger<ConnexeoPartnerLoginHandler> _logger;

public ConnexeoPartnerLoginHandler(ILogger<ConnexeoPartnerLoginHandler> logger)
{
     _logger = logger;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstand me.  The logging actually occurs, but for reasons currently unknown, one important property which is supposed to be automatically provided, is empty.